# Pages File Corrupted LibreOffice 5.0.4.2

Tags: 14.04, libreoffice, macosx

so I am in the process of moving my mom's iMac from OSX to elementary OS freya.  She has hundreds of .pages documents from her mac that she needs to use.  Unfortunately LibreOffice 5.0.4.2 can't load most of the .pages file.  Some of the (simpler) ones work however.  The ones that don't work say that the file is corrupted and when I click repair it fails.  Any solutions?

Comment: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/ only Ubuntu and it's official derivates are supported in AskUbuntu.

Comment: This question does not have to do with anything Elementary OS specific, and more people will see it here.

Comment: @DerekLesho Irrelevant.  Your site references migration from OSX to Elementary Os.  Whether specific to that or not, it is not an Ubuntu OS and not supported here.  Therefore it is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

With Firefox or Chrome visit Apple's iCloud website: https://www.icloud.com .

Register for one Apple ID at no cost and Log in.

Open Pages: https://www.icloud.com/#pages

It asks you to upgrade to a supported browser to use all the features, ignore message: no Linux browsers are supported.

Drag your Pages document onto your browser. It shows you an editable version of your document in a kind of file manager view

Double-click the icon for your uploaded document.

In a new browser tab, it shows you a word processor interface to your document.

Select the tools menu.

Choose 'Download a Copy'.

Export as Microsoft Word.

With LibreOffice, navigate to your downloads folder and open the document.

[Source](https://help.apple.com/icloud/#/mm6f8c20082b)